# In Ubuntu 18.04 I am not able to open windows server machine with double \\ip address

Tags: networking

Till last version of Ubuntu, we can explore shared drive of Windows machine. But in 18.04 its not possible. 
suppose my server ip is 192.168.10.100, it should open with \\192.168.10.100.
Please guide

Answer (score 0):

If your question is referring to the use of a file manager, try entering smb://ip-address

(Add smb: before the slashes and you appear to be using the wrong slash)

In pcmanfm it looks like this

[image]

And in Nautilus like this (I press control-L and type it, but the string I typed in is replaced by "windows share...")

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/838971)

Comment: I believe it does provide an answer to the question!

Comment: I agree that this in some way does provide an answer, but I think it should be more specific in terms of which application to use to use the `smb://ip-address`.